# ¿Por qué me aparece "El identificador string no está definido" en C++?

Tags: c++, array, linux, array-bidimensional

Estoy haciendo unas practicas de arrays en C++ y cuando compilo me aparece este error:

[image: Este es el error que me aparece al compilar]

A parte en mi código no me deja declarar un array de tipo string:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){
  int fila;
  int columna;

  string prueba[4][3]={
      {"[   Materias  ]","[    Maestros   ]","[   Horario   ]"},
      {"[ Matematicas ]","[    Eduardo    ]","[10:00 - 11:00]"},
      {"[   Ciencias  ]","[     Gaston    ]","[11:00 - 12:00]"},
      {"[   Lenguaje  ]","[   Guadalupe   ]","[12:00 - 13:00]"}
  };

  for(fila = 0; fila < 4; fila++){
      for(columna = 0; columna < 3; columna++){
          cout<<prueba[fila][columna];
      }
          cout<<endl;
  }

  return 0;
 }
```

Lo que pasa es que no entiendo por qué no funciona ahora cuando antes se ejecutaba sin problemas.

Comment: Intenta no usar imágenes, ¿porque mejor no pegas tu código?, hay una opción al momento de realizar la pregunta para que puedas darle formato de código.

Comment: Intenta incluir en la cabecera `#include<string>` y declara `std::string prueba[4][3]`.

Comment: Sigue sin funcionar :(

Comment: Acabo de compilar tu programa en G++ sin ningún problema, me parece que tenés algun problema a nivel librerias de sistema operativo. Veo que estás en linux, si ejecutás "whereis string" cual es la salida?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El código funciona bien, yo lo compilé con clang++

[image: terminal]

pero si ves en el segundo, te dará un pequeño error, esto es porque sobrepasas el límite del array, ambos ciclos for debes formularlos de otra forma, por ejemplo:

```
for(fila = 0; fila < 4; fila++)
```

y

```
for(columna = 0; columna < 3; columna++)
```

Comment: revisa si tienes algún otro compilador c/c++ instalado que puedas probar y asegúrate de no utilizar uno para c (string no está definido en c pero si en c++)

Comment: Gracias, estaba sobrepasando el límite del array.